# Cfy Bootstrap Simple Manager SSL CERTIFICATE FAILED

Tags: ssl, centos7, cloudify

I have an issue on my `Centos7` system behind a corporate proxy

```
cfy bootstrap --install-plugins -p /opt/cfy/cloudify-manager-blueprints-commercial/simple-manager-blueprint.yaml -i /opt/cfy/cloudify-manager-blueprints-commercial/simple-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
```

returns

> SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

env http_proxy and https_proxy is set and I've exported

```
CLOUDIFY_SSL_TRUST_ALL=true;
```

```
Collecting https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-fabric-plugin/archive/1.3.1.zip (from -r /tmp/requirements_oUJf1I.txt (line 1))
Command 'pip install -r /tmp/requirements_oUJf1I.txt' executed with an error.
code: 2
error: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 842, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/opt/cfy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:765)
output: None
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what went wrong without looking at the blueprint and the inputs.yaml (after removing all credentials).

Without more data I would simply try to export

`CLOUDIFY_SSL_TRUST_ALL=True;`

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hello,
Thanks Jonathan. I'm gonna try your export, and I will update you.
Blueprint and inputs.yam is the default one. I have an issue when trying to get some python package with https location. (Perhaps because I'm in a venv?)

Comment: Not sure what https location means. Anyway the virtualenv shouldn't be a problem when working with a secure manager. If you have a problem with SSL you can update the openSSL version in the virtualenv

Comment: Jonathan our Proxy, decrypte/encrypt on the fly SSL trafic, and replace certificate by own.
CLOUDIFY_SSL_TRUST_ALL doesn't works.

Comment: Could you try to add the proxy certificate to the resources/ssl/ ?

Comment: it's originally works outside venv. But not in the venv. Do I have to import ssl certificate to cfy venv?